# Letting question owners see Close votes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think it's really sad that people without enough reputation can't see their *own* questions being closed, before it's too late. Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148187/regular-expressions-usage-in-c) could be perfectly legitimate if worded correctly, but we close them (myself included) because they make no sense. However, I think that if the owner is aware of the close votes being cast, he might change the question so that it actually makes sense.

Is there a good reason why people without enough reputation can't see their own questions' close votes?

---

Update:

Just as I'd predicted, someone fixed the question *after* it was closed. :(

Now what if no one reopens it?

Comment: I reopened it...Let's see how long it survives this time. :)

Comment: ...Four good answers. I guess that worked out well.

Comment: @Robert: +1 See what I mean? :)

Comment: Please don't hijack this question into what to do when a question gets closed and then improved! The main point he was trying to make is that owners should see close votes.

Comment: I've frequently seen comments along the lines of "if you don't improve your question quick smart it will be closed". And the OP can take the time to re-compose the question after it has been closed, so do we need more functionality? I would suggest that people under 250 rep haven't been round SO long and will probably miss little cues like that anyway.

Comment: I just love a happy ending!

Comment: @slugster: I beg to differ on the `people under 250 rep haven't been round SO long` (and lol, I get the pun) -- a lot of them are new to asking questions, but not to the site. They'd get the cue if they saw the close button ticking. And sometimes there's not even any comments (except maybe when it's too late), so they might not know otherwise. In any case, I don't see why we'd *lose* anything by giving them that capability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the question has been improved, potentially you can flag it for moderator attention and ask that it be reopened.

[Ducks as other moderators throw their shoes at me]

That process worked pretty well with the question you linked.

Comment: Hm... so there's no chance that the "View close votes" privilege might get changed later for the question's owner? (Any particular reasons why?)

Comment: The programming complexity involved might exceed the benefit.  The link in question serves several purposes, and the current security model is to hide the link completely, which is simple to program but lacks the finer granularity required for the functionality you described.

Comment: Hm... I understand that but it's not too convincing for me. :\ Curious to see what others also think about this. :)

Answer (score 4):

Question owners can see close votes on their own questions at 250 reputation, [per the faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

> 250    Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions

Comment: Oh haha I'd forgotten about that... but still, I'd say that's not enough. Most of the people who have this problem are new (hence why they have this problem), and 250 rep just doesn't happen unless you're *answering* questions here too (which lots of people don't do) or unless you've been asking questions here quite a while (in which case this wouldn't be a problem anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Non-specific to this question, I would really appreciate this ability. I've never understood why close votes had to be secret only to those people who could vote it closed. Having a question randomly close in an OP's face seems like the wrong way to do things

One advantage here is that an OP can dispute a close and sometimes learn more about SE and where to place things (if anywhere).

I see absolutely no positives of hiding close votes at all

Comment: @TheLQ: Are you saying only the original poster should see close votes, or that everyone should?

Comment: I would like to start with the OP just to get somewhere, but in the end it should be open to everyone

Comment: @TheLQ: Why should others be able to see close votes? Is there a good reason? (The only thing it is that, if there are any close votes cast, it discourages the readers of the site, and it reflects negatively upon the person asking the question -- which will ultimately hurt the site in the long run.)

Comment: @Mehrdad Because disputing a question's validity can be done by anyone; its not the OP's sole responsibility. And I simply ask: Why not? There's no harm in doing it, and it removes an if statement from the code

Comment: @TheLQ: But there *is* harm in doing it! It discourages new users from asking questions when they get humiliated in front of everyone. And it also prevents questions from getting answered, because people are less likely to answer a question with close votes, and more likely to cast close votes for it (if they can). There's no real benefit to this. :\

Comment: @Mehrdad That can also happen when an OP see's a close vote then comments "*Why is my question getting closed?*" While less obvious, it still catches most of the people that were going to ask. And I'm confused about the humiliation part: Any question that deserves to get closed gets those comments anyway. Outside of the obvious ones though, I've rarely seen that.

Comment: @TheLQ: Not all questions with close votes get closed, but when *everyone* sees that a question is getting closed, it's a *lot* more likely that fewer people will answer it. (How likely are you to vote for someone that other people are criticizing?)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's slightly more to it than just being able to see the number of votes because people can't "un-vote" to close.

As an example, I had [a question](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/38/56) that had 2 votes to close (with no additional comments), however another user and I explained why the question wasn't a duplicate in the comments.

Two weeks ago (two months after the initial vote-to-close) the question was closed as a duplicate by a mod, with no additional notifications to me.

I noticed it yesterday and have since reworded the question title (which had I done when the initial votes to close had come in would possibly have prevented this) and we've reopened the question.

I found it odd that I hadn't been notified that the question had been closed (as a side note, it's also odd that the votes-to-close don't appear in the timeline or history until the status change happens).